# Show that A belongs to the σ-algebra generated by the intervals

Tags: measure-theory

CAN ANYONE HELP WITH PART (A)

Let A be the set of numbers in the interval [0, 1] that have the digit “0” in the first, second or third place in their decimal expansion.

(a) Show that A belongs to the σ-algebra generated by the intervals.
(Do this by showing that A can be got by applying a countable number of unions/ intersections/complements to suitable intervals.)

(b) Find m(A), where m denotes Lebesgue measure

You first consider the set of numbers with decimal expansion starting with a 0
 i.e [0,1)
.

Then for each one of the 9
 remaining interval [0.1,0.2),[0.2,0.3),…,[0.9,1)
[
0.1
,
0.2
)
,
[
0.2
,
0.3
)
,
…
,
[
0.9
,
1
)
 you then consider the numbers with 0
 as a second digit i.e [0.10,0.11),[0.20,0.21),…,[0.90,0.91)
[
0.10
,
0.11
)
,
[
0.20
,
0.21
)
,
…
,
[
0.90
,
0.91
)
.

And you do it again a third time.

At each step the remaining Lebesgue measure is multiplied by (9/10) therefore after step three (9/10^3)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Visit following link for MathJax tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is a detail that needs to be filled, since, as an example, the number $\frac{1}{10}$ has two decimal expansions, they are $0,1$ and $0,0999...$, then, using the first one, $\frac{1}{10}\notin A$ and the second one, $\frac{1}{10}\in A$. In order to have no contradictions in the construction of $A$, we must fix a cryteria to choose between these two.

This phenomenom of duplicated decimal expansions occurs with numbers of the form $0,a_1a_2a_3...a_n1$, since
$$
0,a_1a_2a_3...a_n1 = 0,a_1a_2a_3...a_n09999999999...
$$

What does happen is that **any number has an unique infinite decimal expansion (here, by infinite, we mean a decimal expansion that has infinite non-zero algarisms)**, so, in the construction of $A$, we must consider the infinite decimal expansion of the number.

Let $A_1$ be the set of numbers that have 0 at the first place of their infinite decimal expansion. Then $A_1$ is precisely $\left[0,\frac{1}{10}\right]$, for if $\alpha\in\left[0,\frac{1}{10}\right]$, then the infinite decimal expansion of $\alpha$, say $0,a_1a_2a_3...a_n...$, satisfies
$$
0,a_1a_2a_3...a_n...\leq \frac{1}{10} = 0,09999,
$$
and, since $0,a_1a_2a_3...a_n...$ has infinite non-zero algarisms, we must have $a_1=0$.

Now, let $A_2$ be the set of numbers with a non-zero algarism at the first place and $0$ at the second place. First, we get the set of numbers that have $0$ in **both** first and second place. This set is precisely $\left[0,\frac{1}{100}\right]$ (to conclude that, you just need a similar argument to the above one). Then, the set of numbers with $1$ in the first place and $0$ in the second is
$$
\frac{1}{10}+\left[0,\frac{1}{100}\right].
$$
The set of numbers with $2$ in the first place and $0$ in the second is
$$
\frac{2}{10}+\left[0,\frac{1}{100}\right],
$$
and so on.

Then, $A_2$ is the union of the sets above for each $n\in\{1,...,9\}$, that is
$$
A_2=\bigcup_{n=1}^9 \frac{n}{10}+\left[0,\frac{1}{100}\right].
$$

Finally, we must consider the set $A_3$ of numbers that has non-zero algarisms at the first **and** second places and has $0$ at the third place. The set of numbers that have $0$ at **both** the first and second places is $\left[0,\frac{1}{1000}\right]$. Then, the set of numbers that have the algarism $a_1$ in the first place, $a_2$ in the second place and $0$ at the third place is
$$
0,a_1a_2+\left[0,\frac{1}{1000}\right].
$$
Then $A_3$ will be the union
$$
A_3=\bigcup_{a_1=1}^9\left(\bigcup_{a_2=1}^9 0,a_1a_2+\left[0,\frac{1}{1000}\right]\right).
$$

Finally, just note that $A=A_1\cup A_2 \cup A_3$, and each one is the union of closed intervals.

Another way to conclude this, which is faster but harder, is to fix the set $B=\{0,a_1a_2a_3: a_i=0,\mbox{ for some i\in\{1,2,3\}}$ and prove that
$$
A=\bigcup_{b\in B} b+\left[0,\frac{1}{1000}\right].
$$

Comment: Is this in Responce to part (a) ?

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer to part (a) carefully explained and with details. After reading that you may give a more sucint answer of your own based on the intuition given by my text. If you are out of patience to that, skip it to the last paragraph, then return the text to fulfill the gaps.

Comment: Okay perfect thank you! There is a lot there to consider! I'm going to study the detailed description so I know for again how to tackle sigma algebras!

Comment: You're welcome. If you find this helpful, please press the "check" sign on the answer, so everyone knows that it has already been answered.

Comment: Thank you! No problem